# Getting the row number of a hyperlinked cell in open calc

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I have a file with two spreadsheets, Sheet1 and Sheet2.

In Sheet1 I have cells that link to a specific cell in Sheet2. This is done, using OpenCalc's HYPERLINK function.

Let's assume I use the following function in Sheet1.A1:

```
=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2.D4","SomeText")
```

In Sheet1.A2 I would like to fetch the row number of the linked cell (Sheet2.D4), so the end result to be 4(as the 4th row from Sheet2 is linked)

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is only for `=HYPERLINK()` formulas for such internal cell links, then it can be achieved with this formula:

```
=MID(FORMULA(A1),SEARCH("[0-9]+(?!.*\.)",FORMULA(A1)),SEARCH("[;,]",FORMULA(A1))-SEARCH("[0-9]+(?!.*\.)",FORMULA(A1))-1)
```

More universal would be a macro solution.

Greetings

Axel